# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) webresource.axd , scripresource.axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, web-application-firewall

[image]

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
Request_Details.aspx:88 Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
    at Request_Details.aspx?RequestID=55204:88
ScriptResource.axd:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
Request_Details.aspx:101 Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined

and i added this code to web config

but not worde also

Comment: The server did not like the request you sent.  The server got the request and then sent back a 500 error message.  You can cature the request that was sent using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare against the vendors documentation, or against another tools that did work.  Normally the defaults headers in first request from c# are not correct and you have to either change the default headers or add missing headers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [SO guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: have you find the solution for this issue?